# fck editor ajax data load not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, editor, fckeditor

fck editor load ajax data not working why?
question is teaxarea. post data into $("#question").val(data.question);
but not show textarea editor.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "get_q.php",
     data: ('.$formParams.'),
     type: "POST",
     datatype: "json",
     success: function (data) {
         if (data.ret_val == "ok") {
             $("#ad_edit_id").val(data.id);
             $("#question").val(data.question);

         }
         if (data.ret_val == "error") {
             alert("error");
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: what is this: data: ('.$formParams.')